# How to dynamic content of a page (LinkedIn search) with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

Certain pages load content **after user scrolls past a certain threshold**. For 
example, LinkedIn.com's search bar returns a page where only the **first 4-6 results** are initially present in the HTML. In reality, as you scroll down the embedded javascript will load additional profiles to show a total of **10-12** results.

Hence, if I want to get all profiles within the page using Selenium, I need to simulate user's scrolling action.
I tried to use `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,1000);")` but this seems to only work when the driver is running in an active window. If my driver is running in the background, the Javascript will not load additional profiles.

Is there a way to force javascript to load all elements? I tried `driver.execute_script("window.focus();")` with no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used and seems to be working for me.
I use it for linkedin webscraping.

```
for i in range(5000):
    browse = "window.scrollTo(0," + str(i) + ")"
    browser.execute_script(browse)
    i = i + 400
```

Hope it helps you out!